# Find equivalent String in huge Compilation of Strings

Tags: c#, string, performance, compilation

I wrote a C# Program, that holds parsed data consisting of a List of Headers, which in turn carries a list of IDs represented with a String.

Email: List<Headers> ; Header: List<IDs>

// ONE random ID (of about 100 but up to 2000) uniquely identifies one Header in an Index. I upload ALL IDs i parsed to a Server which in turn searches the Index for the IDs, deletes the corresponding Header and writes a Logfile with the IDs it deleted and the IDs that weren't on the Index.

My next step is to parse the LogFile for the deleted IDs and find the Equivalent IDs in my compilation and mark its Header als Deleted.

The Result of the Logparsing is an array with all successfully deleted IDs.

so it looks like this:

```
foreach(string deletedID in deletedIDs){
   foreach(EMail mail in mails){
      foreach(Header header in mail.headers){
          if(header.Deleted == false){
             for(string iD in header) {
                if(deletedID == iD) header.Deleted = true;
             }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I was wondering, if there was a more efficient way to do this (or even more ways)

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you want.  Perhaps if you provided an example.

Comment: What Robert said. You also might look at a binary tree as a simple way of searching through a list of IDs, if that's what you mean, but it's not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: There is a faster way to search - hashtable, aka Dictionary<K,V>. Calculate hash for each item you want found (IDs you parse from file) as your key, your value will depend on what is it you're doing

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers so far! Sorry for being unclear in my question - i updated it to make things clearer.

Comment: Are you talking about Java or C#? Your code seems like Java. Or maybe it's a pseudo-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to hold your data using the `ID` as the key and `Email` or `Header` as the value seems reasonable here. This makes your searches almost instantaneous.